# Shared files between projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

We have a web based system with three different front ends. We've recently splitted these into three projects, all in one solution.
We also have a common project in the solution, for helpers and such.
What i'm looking for is a way to put shared css, js and image resources in the common project to be easily accessed by all three front end projects.
I'm aware of the "Add as link", and that works fine for resources like a central css. But, we have a directory with a whole bunch of images, icons and such. I would like this directory to be visible under /Content/ for all projects, and get updated if i add new files in the common project.

In unix/linux i would have easily solved this with a synlink. Can i do a similar solution in a MS environment, or is there some other way to do this that's prefered?

Answer (score 2):

I think that **Junctions** might be what you are looking for, see [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouOrganizeYourCode.aspx) from Scott Hanselman for more info. Uou can download the **Junctions** tool from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com).

Junctions are NTFS Reparse Points, also known as symlinks and are like shortcuts, but much more powerful.

Comment: I use this tool http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html to create junctions. They seem like a suitable way to solve the problem.